# Statically link libcurl to project (Still requires DLL)

Tags: c++, netbeans, dll, libcurl, libcrypto

I'm using Netbeans IDE with C/C++ plugin.

My code compiles without any problem.
`CURL_STATICLIB` is defined (`-DCURL_STATICLIB` also tried `#define CURL_STATICLIB`).

[image: Linked libs]

This is all my linked libs.

I'm trying to avoid packaging the exe with multiple DLLs, so I'm trying to statically link it.

Even though after link I still get the dependency errors.
(libcurl.dll libeay32.dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out how to do it.
I just wanted to share it so maybe it could help someone :).

Go to
Right click your project > Properties > C++ Compiler > Type in Preprocessor Definitions

> HTTP_ONLY CURL_STATICLIB WITH_SSH2=STATIC

And you still need to link this libraries

> curl
>   ssh2
>   idn
>   ssl
>   crypto
>   wldap32
>   rtmp
>   z (Libz or zip)
>   ws2_32
>   winmm

NOTE: arrangement should be also the same

CURL_STATICLIB only didn't work for me
I did a little research on CURL compiler definitions and tried this, then it worked.